# distribute xamarin ios app

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new to xamarin and I have made my first app but currently I don't want to connect to AppStore for distributing.What should I do to be able to distribute my app without using AppStore? 
By the way, I'm using visual studio 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribute your app for iOS device you will need to submit it to Apple for review so it can be placed in the AppStore.
For this you will need an paid Apple Developer account.

With paid developers account you can also create a AdHoc version of you app which can be install on registered device, you can only register a 100 device per year. Also the profile will expire after max one year so you will need to register the device.

There is the option for the Enterprise distribution account, this means that you will need to DUNS number and a secure site to host the app yourself. But there big draw back for this type of account is that official you can only have employees of the company owning the account install the app.

tl;dr: Appstore or none.

Comment: I'm not trying to distribute my app to appstore For now , I'm interested to host my own opp .Do I need to submit to appStore for that ?

Comment: No you don't. If you want to install it on your own testing devices, then you don't need to submit to the app store.

Comment: You can only host your own app if you use the Enterprise program, but this limits you to only employees of the company on hows name the account is. Apple might cancel you account if you miss use it. So if you want to distribute to every one the AppStore is your only option.

Comment: @j.edga If you are looking for `any` type of public use of your app, the AppStore is the only way to go (unless all your user's phones are jailbroken). Apple does *not* permit Google/Android style of installing from 'unknown sources' via a public http based url to the .apk

Comment: @RobertN thanks, I have xamarin Enterprise But What's the way if I don't want to submit my app to AppStore?What's the solution to install from unknown sources?

Comment: @j.edga You can not install from an unknown issue on iOS unless you jailbreak your phone.... otherwise like rckoenes' answer above: app store, register up to 100 ad-hoc devices and renew each year or setup an enterprise acct with apple.